# XML - getting data to go into a table (formatting)?

Tags: xml, xslt

I want my code to appear in a table. With the headers Name, Address and Order to be one row. Then the data to appear in separate rows below, so each customer has their own row. At the moment they all appear below each other.

```
<xsl:template match="/Customers">
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Customer Orders</h1>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="Customer/CustomerName" >
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Address</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="Customer/CustomerAddress" >
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Order</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="Customer/OrderDesc" >
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seeing your input and the expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **probably** want to do:

```
<xsl:template match="/Customers">
    <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Customer Orders</h1>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Order</th>
                </tr>   
                <xsl:for-each select="Customer" >
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="CustomerName"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="CustomerAddress"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="OrderDesc"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Untested, because no code was provided.